# The statement : "If $x \in \varnothing$ then $x \notin A$" is true

Tags: elementary-set-theory

It is a well known fact that the statement $T$: "If $x \in \varnothing$ then $x \in A$" is true. That is, the null set is a subset of any set $A$.

The statement $S$ : "If $x \in \varnothing$ then $x \notin A$" is also true because the antecedent $x \in \varnothing$ for all $x$ is false.

Is the statement $S$ is contradictory with the statement $T$?

Comment: x can't be an element of the empty set - the empty set has no elements.

Comment: $p \to q$ is equivalent to $\lnot p \lor q$. Thus, $p \to \lnot q$ is $\lnot p \lor \lnot q$. Now, $\lnot p \lor q$ and $\lnot p \lor \lnot q$ are not *contradictory* because (see @Asaf's answer) they are both "compatible" with the situation where $p$ is *false* : in your case, $p$ is $x \in \emptyset$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are not contradictory since $x\in\varnothing$ is a false statement anyway.

It just shows that $\varnothing$ is a subset of $A^c$, or a subclass if you work in a set theory without a universal set.